# How do I attach frilly extension of skirt using a sewing machine WITHOUT the thread appearing on the front of the skirt?

Tags: sewing, sewing-machine, technique-selection

How do I attach frilly extension of skirt using a sewing machine WITHOUT the thread appearing on the front of the skirt?

Without sewing machine only alternative to sew on the frilly extension is to blind-stitch by hand.

Thank you

[image: Front of skirt]

[image: Back of skirt]

Comment: blind stitch hem function on your machine. manual should give you the instructions.

Comment: @NotTheFace oh my! My Singer 1304 sewing machine have blind stitch hem, and some tutorials say I need special foot. Another tutorial says most machines have poor blind hem stitch function, unless it is an industrial sewing machine. Oh dear!

Comment: The old-fashioned way: pin the skirt and the flounce together, right sides together, and sew a straight-stitch seam.  Then use your iron to flatten things out.  The seam allowance should be flipped up.  By the way for this approach, you'll want to use straight pins for the pinning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If what I see in the picture is what’s up, this should do it.

So, what I see is the plaid skirt with a serged hem that is folded up and hemmed with a professional blind stitch machine.

Remove the blind hem stitch. There is a trick to remove the thread with one pull if you start at the right spot. Regardless, remove that hem, without removing the serged edge. Then, using the instructions in your 1304’s manual blind hem it.

[image: page 27 Singer 1304 manual]

See in illustration #2 how the zig zag hits the fabric, this would be the “right” side or front/showing side of the garment. Because the one zig zag stitch hits all and not the straight stitch, this is what makes it a blind hem. Of course there are ways to fold the fabric before stitching, which is pretty generic in this manual. You probably want to practice the blind hem with scrap fabric to get a feel for the method.

The idea is to “marry” or “kiss” the fabrics together so when you pull on the finished piece the thread is pulled to the back. This is what makes it disappear.

[image: wiki pic]

Let's use this illustration and identify with your materials:
#1 blue - plaid fabric front/right side
#1 green - plaid fabric folded
#1 red - both plaid & frill
#1 green - frill
#1 light green  - frill

The orange “top view” is how the stitch should appear on the inside (wrong side) once pulled and pressed.
#2 shows the cross section view finished.
This is where you have to think creatively to attach the correct side of the frill. That’s why I highly recommend practicing on scraps and identifying front/back so you fold correctly.  I know I would attach the frill backwards on my first try. ☺️

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: very helpful, very through!

Comment: thank you, maybe you can post a pic of it finished and mention what parts of the process worked. If you have time. Happy sewing! ☺️

Comment: I shall try @not-the-face